# Solution of Windows 8.1 in VS 2015 in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

My machine has Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015

I have downloaded a Stores Application Sample for "Windows 8.1" Solution and opened it, then tried to run it in simulator but it is showing the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP1630 : Invalid "TargetOsVersion" property in the recipe file "C:\Users\**\Downloads\JavaCameraCaptureUI Sample (1)\JavaScript\bin\Debug\CameraCaptureUI.build.appxrecipe"    CameraCaptureUI
```

The same has been running well with VS 2013.

What could be the Solution?

Comment: have you installed the Win8.1 tools in VS2015 setup?

Comment: Specifically I am not if I did, I might not be as I just installed VS2015. Can you pls share me link for it as  I could not get any from web search..

Comment: go to desktop control panel->programs & features and select the VS2015, click on modify and in the advanced options, look if the 8.1 tools are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a few hours of reducing it discovered these two lines in the project (.jsproj) file:

```
<VisualStudioVersion>12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

I removed them from the file and everything started working great (open and edit it with Notepad, while VS being closed).